# Visual Studio Script Debugging - Invalid Process 'Type' for inetinfo.exe

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis, asp-classic

I'm having an issue debugging a Classic ASP application from Visual Studio. When I attach to the inetinfo.exe process, I'm getting the message

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

I think I've isolated the issue as being an incorrect process type being given to inetinfo.exe.

The following screenshot shows what i see when I select 'Debug -> Attach to Process' in Visual Studio 2010:

[image: inetinfo incorrect process type]

The inetinfo.exe process "Type" is reported as

> T-SQL, Managed (v2.0.50727), x86

Whereas, I would expect it to be:

> T-SQL, Script, x86

I have script debugging turned on in IIS, and the application protection level is low. Incidentally, if I flip the application level to medium or high, I see the same on dllhost.exe.

To reiterate, I am trying to debug a Classic ASP Script application, not a managed ASP.NET application.

Is there any reason why (I assume) IIS is getting itself in a pickle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I should have read my own article on this ([Debugging Classic ASP From Visual Studio 2010](http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2010/10/12/debugging-classic-asp-from-visual-studio-2010/)):

Floundering around, I ran this:

```
regsvr32.exe "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\pdm.dll"
```

After an IIS restart I found that this fixed it.

For anyone else toiling with this issue, there is an excellent section in the following article: [How to Debug Script Code Using Visual Studio .NET](http://cj-chung.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/how-to-debug-script-code-using-visual.html). The section you are looking for is titled **"There is no “Script” option for attaching to the script host**"